# Why doesn't linearity of squaring over Galois Field imply linearity of cubing?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

I am reading through [this paper](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/block-cipher-techniques/documents/bcm/comments/cwc-gcm/ferguson2.pdf) and in $\S$3.3 it describes how for $GF(2^{128})$ it is easy to show that squaring is linear, i.e. because the field is of characteristic 2 so the cross term vanishes. To make this clear, we have:

$(a + b)^2=a^2 + 2ab + b^2$,

but as the field is of characteristic 2 the middle term vanishes and we are left with:

$a^2 + b^2$.

If we were to consider cubing with the above 'high-school algebra' (sorry, I don't know a better description here) notation, then cubing clearly isn't linear because if we multiply in another factor we get:

$(a^2 + b^2) \cdot (a + b) = a^3 + a^2b + ab^2 + b^3$,

and the middle terms no longer vanish over a field of characteristic 2.

However, in the paper above the author generalises to a matrix represenation, and shows that (which makes sense, due to the linearity) squaring can be represented as a matrix, that is:

$\bar X^2 = \mathbf{M_S}\bar X$.

However, now I can write the cube as:

$\bar X^3 = \bar X^2 \cdot \bar X = \mathbf{M_S}\bar X \cdot \bar X = \mathbf{M_S}\bar X^2 = \mathbf{M_S}^2\bar X$.

I know that this can't be write, in particular because I know that it should be that:

$\bar X^4 = \mathbf{M_S}^2\bar X$.

However, I can't see what is wrong with the above manipulation. Can someone help point out my mistake, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you mathematically define $ \bar A \cdot \bar B$? For $GF(2^{128})$, inner product produces a single bit scalar, outer product produces a 128 by 128 bit matrix.

Although a matrix can be used to implement mapping, think of it as a function, and $map(a)⋅b≠map(a⋅b)$. If the mapping is linear, $map(a⋅b)=map(a)⋅map(b)$ . If the mapping is isomorphic, then also $map(a+b)=map(a)+map(b)$

Comment: I see. In this case, I am expecting that squaring a field element should produce another field element, which I am then currently understanding as a 128-element column vector/polynomial like it was originally. Actually just starting to think about this aspect of the set-up is quite enlightening because it's harder to see how you would define the squaring as an inner/outer product to preserve this structure. Your comments about the mapping are helpful, but could you elaborate what this is meaning a little further, please, I am unfamiliar with these terms? Thanks!

Comment: @whatf0xx - a field element is technically a polynomial. Multiplication can be implemented by multiplying two field elements modulo the field polynomial. The paper mentions other representations of field elements, such as an array of coefficients to a polynomial, and multiplication still operates as it does with polynomials. For the mapping the paper mentions changing the representation to a transposed vector of coefficients, effectively a 128 row by 1 bit matrix. The mapping is then done by multiplying a 128 row by 128 bit mapping matrix times a 128 row by 1 bit element.

Comment: @whatf0xx - For a matrix multiply the inner dimensions have to match: such as an `a` row by `b` column matrix times a `b` row by `c` column matrix, resulting in a `a` by `c` result. What isn't clear in the paper is that $ \bar X^2$ really means polynomial multiplication: $X^2 = X \cdot X$, then changing the representation of $X^2$ to $ \bar X^2$ . The paper mentions multiplying a vector times a constant (scalar), but doesn't mention multiplication of two vectors.

Comment: Thanks, for the help, I think I understand better now:)